# AngularJS value from radio to $http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, radio-button

I wold like to ask you how to get value from radio and send it with $http.post using AngularJS. Here is some example

**HTML**

```
  <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test1" value="4"/>
  <label for="test1">Four paintings</label>

  <input name="group1" type="radio" id="test2" value="6" />
  <label for="test2">Six paintings</label>

  <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
```

One radio button has value of 4 and another 6. These numbers I would like to send to Angular and then to DB

**Angular**

```
$scope.submit = function(){
  if ( radioValue == 4 ) {
     $http.post(apiURL, {
        numberOfpaintings: ??, // radioValue
        ...      
       });
   } else if( radioValue == 6 ) {
     $http.post(apiURL, {
        numberOfpaintings: ??, // radioValue
        ...
       });
   }
}
```

That 'radioValue' is just some made up value that should somehow store that value from radioButtons.
Thanks!

Comment: use `ng-model = "radioValue"` in your input tags

Comment: Perhaps add `data-ng-model="radioValue"` to each radio button and then use `$scope.radioValue` in your code instead of `radioValue`

Comment: and then I can access it in angular file by using $scope.radioValue ?
for example `(if $scope.radioValue == 4) {...}`

Comment: @daf Ok I'll try it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/b3AAr9XlVcS0IW962tUT

In script:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.paintings = 4;

  $scope.submit = function(){

  alert($scope.paintings);

 $http.post(apiURL, {
    numberOfpaintings: $scope.paintings
   });
 }
});
```

in html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<input name="group1" ng-model="paintings" type="radio" id="test1" value="4"/>
<label for="test1">Four paintings</label>

<input name="group1"  ng-model="paintings" type="radio" id="test2" value="6" />
 <label for="test2">Six paintings</label>

<button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>


</body>
```

Comment: the `$scope.paintings = 4;`on the third line is setting the default radio?

Comment: yes this value will default select the radio button on page load.

Comment: Well the `alert($scope.paintings)` does work, but when I check Database then the sent value is always '0'. Maybe I need to convert it to Number?

Comment: Could you show me complete post method, and the way you are receiving the value in the server API

Comment: also I would like to perform different .post to according to the selected radio

Comment: is the object on your server side has the matching data model as you have in your post method ? you can post on different url based on the paintings value . Set  apiURL = ($scope.paintings == 4) ? "URLfor4":"URLfor6";

Comment: Ahh now it works. I had a typo in my PHP code. Thanks a lot. Yes I'll definitely try that thing with URL's. Thanks again